# How to import csv file in magento

Tags: magento, import

I have magento platform and i have parent/child products.I want to import new products using csv file or any format file in magento.Please guide me how to import products data in magento.

When i export data in csv file format then data is not in proper format.Please tell me i have to design csv file in that format?

Answer (score 1):

First export a csv file file from System->Import/Export->Export and click continue at the end of the page. This way you will get a format how your csv should be.
Then add all the details in it regarding your new products. Import the file using same System->Import/Export->Import.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Is there any php code involve to generate csv file or not?

Comment: If some one have time then please help me.When i export data then data is not in proper format i.e is in one line.

Comment: Just go in excel settings ang check whether its seperate by comma or not. It might be because of that